# Fail safe when renaming files (Selenium Chromedriver)

Tags: powershell, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Below you can see a part of the code I have written to script something with PowerShell and Selenium Chromedriver. As you can see, the code looks for the first element in the download folder and renames and transfers it to the right location.

Now I want to build in a fail safe for when for a reason file won't download right. The script should stop in order to avoid renaming the wrong files.

```
# Select last downloaded file
$dir = "C:\Users\SVan37\Downloads"
$first = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending | 
Select-Object -First 1
$first.name

# rename file to standard name "edi_iris.xlsx and move it to the right location**
Rename-Item C:\Users\SVan37\Downloads\$first edi_iris.xlsx
Move-Item C:\Users\SVan37\Downloads\edi_iris.xlsx C:\Users\SVan37\Documents\test -force
```

Comment: As your script (as it is) doesn't have any information of what file to expect, it's kind of hard to build a fail safe? At least not in an automatic way.

Comment: The script should stop when $first is empty or when it is not a excel file. Is this possible?

Comment: You will need an `if` statement to check for it. In addition you could just get `.xlsx` files using the `Get-ChildItem` statement. But that would require you to actually download an `.xlsx` file.